# Implementing Android LocationListener in a widget

Tags: android, geolocation, widget

I am working on a widget for Android, which displays your current location. To get the current latitude and longitude I have the following code:

```
public class LocationInfo extends Activity {

RemoteViews remoteViews;

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
myLocationListener locationListener = new myLocationListener();
LocationProvider locationProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);

class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null)
        {
            double Long = location.getLongitude();
            double Lat = location.getLatitude();

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview3, Double.toString(Long));
        }

        else {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview3, "LOADING...");
        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
}
```

However, I get an error at the arguments of requestLocationUpdates. It says **"Syntax error on tokens, VariableDeclarator expected instead"** at 0,0, locationListener.

Also, this is a separate class. How would I then run this in my widget? Something like:

```
LocationInfo locationProvider = new LocationInfo();
LocationProvider.run();
```

maybe? Again, any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to execute

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

outside of methods.
Just move in to, for example, `onCreate` of Activity.

Good luck

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, but I think I can't use onCreate in here because I am implementing it in a widget ultimately, right?

Comment: Yes. I think you should start a service that will be listening for location changes and request widget updates. And in this update you will be able to fill Widget with data, related to last known location.

Comment: So then I would be able to do it like this? Because I can just gather the information in this seperate Activity, and then call this Activity in my main file which is the widget? If I am wrong here, could you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with widgets, however, I think it's not intented to manipulate them from Activity, and of course you cannot store references to them in Activity, as it can be destroyed by system anytime, but widget - not.
Keep a look at this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html . For my understanding you should provide a provider, that will be triggered by system, and it will manipulate the widget with RemoveView interface. Are you planning to do like this?

Comment: Yes, my idea was to provide the widget with a provider, and in this provider I make a call to the LocationInfo activity. Then in the LocationInfo Activity I gather the information and use RemoteViews to display it. So basically, I tell the provider to run the Activity, in which all the work is done. But I'm not completely sure that I can do this, and also exactly how I would do this..

Comment: Hmm.. You mean that this activity will handle some user input and from that will fill the widget? It sounds strange, as, for example, your widget provider will be queried every device boot, I don't think that you actually want to show your activity to user each time.
And if it does not handle user operations or even invisible/transparent - so why you'll need the activity at all?

Comment: Ok I think you are right in that I don't need the external Activity. I will just try to build it into the widget itself using a service then.. I hope that's possible :) .